# Button listner not working in android studio

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to create an application that moves data between two activities, but when launched the button clicked event doesn't switch to the second activity.

MainActivity.kt :

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val binding:ActivityMainBinding = 
        DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this,R.layout.activity_main)

        val myBundle = Bundle()
        val button = binding.button

        button.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
            val val1 = binding.val1.text.toString()
            val val2 = binding.val2.text.toString()
            val r = val1.toDouble()+val2.toDouble()

            binding.valeur1=val1.toDouble()
            binding.valeur2=val2.toDouble()
            binding.resultat=r

            myBundle.putDouble("val1",val1.toDouble())
            myBundle.putDouble("val2",val2.toDouble())
            myBundle.putDouble("result",r)
            Log.d("clicked","clicked")
            val myIntent = Intent(this,MainActivity2::class.java)
            myIntent.putExtras(myBundle)
            startActivity(myIntent)
        })
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        val binding: ActivityMainBinding =
            DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)
        if (binding.valeur1 != null) {
            val val1 = binding.val1
            val val2 = binding.val2
            val somme = binding.textView2
            val1.setText(binding.valeur1.toString())
            val2.setText(binding.valeur2.toString())
            val txt = binding.resultat.toString()
            somme.text = "La somme est $txt"
        }
    }
}
```

and I can't figure out where is the problem

Comment: but you don't have 2 activities here, you have one ? and why do you have `setContentView` twice ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your activity is launched `onCreate` is called but then `onResume()` is called after see https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle

You are calling `DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this,R.layout.activity_main)` in both `onCreate` and `onResume`.

Therefore by the time, your view is actually visible your setting of the `onClick` listener is overridden by the rerun of `DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this,R.layout.activity_main)` in `onResume`

Comment: So i should declare the binding in the outer scoop if I'm not wrong?

Comment: It's not a nested scope. `onCreate()` and `onResume()` are two events in the lifecycle. You just need to remove the `setContentView()` call from `onResume()` because it is removing all the previously set views.

Comment: @yahyaBdd if my answer solved your issue please mark it as accepted. thank you